# c++ functional programming ( boost::phoenix && boost::spirit) testing for null-ptrs in pointer placeholders

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix, null-pointer

So, I have the following spirit karma rule body:

```
base_rule = 
    eps(_r1 != 0) [ // _r1 is a pointer_typed placeholder
        eps
    ]
;
```

which leads to a rather long error message from g++ which (helpfully) ends with :

```
/opt/dev_64_swat/Boost/include/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/operator/comparison.hpp
:37:5: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer 
[-fpermissive]
```

This is valid c++:

```
struct zebra{};

int main()
{
  zebra * x;
  if( x == 0);  
}
```

I thought to try `boost::phoenix::static_cast_<_r1_type *>(0)` as well as converting `_r1_type` to a integer (yes that is WRONG, it was just an experiment).

**The question:**

How can I use a spirit eps construct to perform a pointer test on a placeholder to prevent  rule body evaluation when the point is zero ?

As with all "C++ functional programming library usage" questions I expect the answer to leave me feeling like a dimwit.

**The Answer**

Ildjam's point directly answers my question. There were two issues with my problem; there is a indirect problem above. And that is to do with conditionals in PEG. What I am trying to express should be written as such:

```
rule = ( eps(_r) << ( /* grammar for when pointer is not null */ ) ) 
    | eps // otherwise dont do anything.
;
```

I was using the semantic action body ( specified in a  [] block), to express the conditional part of the grammar. Strangely though I have written conditional PEG grammars before, I just made a mistake, which led to the second class of problems.

So, eps(_r1) does the trick, The second type of compilation issue is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Have you tried using implicit pointer-to-`bool` conversion? `base_rule = eps(_r1)[/*impl*/];`

Comment: (+1) Yes my brain threw that up after the `static_cast_` attempts, alas it did not work. If you want the error message I can add it to my question.

Comment: No, I don't think the errors will be useful in this case, just figured I'd ask before trying to compile it myself. :-]

Comment: Actually, given that it works for me, maybe those errors are of interest after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using implicit pointer-to-`bool` conversion, as suggested in my comment, works for me out of the box with Boost 1.46.1. The following is a minimal repro wherein `parse` succeeds if (and only if) `p != 0 && input == "not null"` or `p == 0 && input == "null"`:

```
#include <string>
#include <ios>
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace qi = spirit::qi;

struct test_grammar : qi::grammar<std::string::const_iterator, void(int*)>
{
    test_grammar() : base_type(start_)
    {
        start_
            =   (   spirit::eps(spirit::_r1)
                    >> "not null"
                |   spirit::eps(!spirit::_r1)
                    >> "null"
                )
                >> spirit::eoi
            ;
    }

private:
    qi::rule<base_type::iterator_type, base_type::sig_type> start_;
};
test_grammar const test;

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    int* p = &i;                          // alternatively, = 0;
    std::string const input = "not null"; // alternatively, = "null";

    std::string::const_iterator first = input.begin();
    std::cout
        << std::boolalpha
        << "parse succeeded: "
        << qi::parse(first, input.end(), test(p))
        << std::endl;
}
```

So, whatever problem you're having while trying to use implicit conversion in this manner, it must be specific to your code; i.e., you'll have to show more of your code to get any useful feedback.

Comment: You were right, see comments in my question for the problem I was having.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fundamental problem with the C++ type system in C++03. The *value* 0 is special and can be used in many places where it's *type*, `int`, cannot. This problem is easily demonstrated and causes plenty of problems where templates and pointers combine.

```
void f(int i) {
    void* ptr = ...;
    if (ptr == i) { // MALFORMED
    }
}

f(0); // But I'm trying to compare with 0, which is legit!

template<typename T, typename Y> T construct_from(const Y& y) {
    return T(y);
}
construct_from<void*>(0); // ERROR, cannot construct ptr from int.
```

The simplest solution is to write a quick version of `nullptr`, which can be found in C++0x.

```
struct nullptr_t {
    template<typename T> operator T*() const {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: The _simplest_ solution is to stop comparing to literal `0` and evaluate the pointer as a `bool`. ;-]

Comment: @ildjam. I tried that, its not a runtime c++ problem, its (potentially) a problem with the phoenix / spirit constructs (or my understanding thereof). I will try to isolate the code into a compileable test grammar.

Comment: @Hassan : Did you try the code in my answer? If it works, then it's definitely a problem specific to your grammar; if it doesn't, then I'm quite confused. ;-]